# purify UMR error with boost::unordered_set

Tags: c++, boost

I have this simple code:

```
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::unordered_set<int> bset;
    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
        bset.insert(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I create a purify build and run, I am getting the following UMR (uninitialized memory read) error. I could not figure out how to get rid of this.

> ****  Purify instrumented app_pure (pid 21943)  ****
>
> UMR: Uninitialized memory read (10000 times):
>
> - This is occurring while in thread 21943:
>
>   std::pair>, bool > boost::unordered::detail::table_impl, int, boost::hash, std::equal_to >>::emplace_impl>(int const&, boost::unordered::detail::set, int, boost::hash, std::equal_to > const&) [unique.hpp:414]
>     std::pair>, bool > boost::unordered::detail::table_impl, int, boost::hash, std::equal_to >>::emplace(boost::unordered::detail::emplace_args1, int, boost::hash, std::equal_to >> const&) [unique.hpp:393]
>     std::pair, boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node const* >, bool > boost::unordered::unordered_set, std::equal_to, std::allocator >::emplace(int const&) [unordered_set.hpp:277]
>     boost::unordered::unordered_set, std::equal_to, std::allocator >::insert(int const&) [unordered_set.hpp:380]
>
>   main           [app.cxx:8]
>
>   __libc_start_main [libc.so.6]
>
>   _start         [crt1.o]
>
>   - Reading 8 bytes from 0x7fffffffd668 on the stack of thread 21943 (7 bytes at 0x7fffffffd669 uninit).
>   - Address 0x7fffffffd668 is       56 bytes past start of local variable "pos" in function std::pair>, bool > boost::unordered::detail::table_impl, int, boost::hash, std::equal_to >>::emplace_impl>(int const&, boost::unordered::detail::set, int, boost::hash, std::equal_to > const&).

My boost version is 1.54.0

My GCC version is 4.8.3

Purify version is 7.3 (Purify 7.3-mod1 150930 Linux (64-bit))

Can anyone please give any hint on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Hocine - no unfortunately I don't have. I use the one installed in my organization.

Comment: ok, i'm trying to find it, in order to help if possible

Comment: Mildly interesting. Please post _exact_ compiler/linker flags. Of course, the snippet isn't at fault. So, check the generated assembly listing.

Comment: I downloaded this file PPlus.7.0.1.0-008.tar for Linux, I’m trying to install on Redhat 6.4, do you have an idea how to get a trial license for Purify? The license file extension is upd